# passing parameters to the concatenate function

Tags: c++

i'm confused with `*this = *this +rhs;` , should i use `this = this +rhs;` instead or it will be wrong because the `Mystring Mystring::operator+(Mystring &rhs)` const expect object not reference of object???
i'm using the concatenate function to do the assign and concatenate.

```
////concatenate
Mystring Mystring::operator+(Mystring &rhs) const
{
    std::cout << "concatenate" << std::endl;
    size_t buff_size = strlen(this.str)+strlen(rhs.str)+1;
    char *buff = new char[buff_size];
    std::strcpy(buff,str);
    std::strcat(buff,rhs);
    Mystring temp {buff};
    delete [] buff;
    return temp;
}


//concatenate and assign    s1= s1+ ****
Mystring &Mystring::operator+=(const Mystring &rhs)
{
    *this = *this +rhs;
    return *this;
}


//repeat  s1 = s2 * 3
Mystring Mystring::operator*(int n) const
{
    Mystring temp;
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;++i)
        temp = temp + *this;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: If you actually try `this = this +rhs;`, you'd discover that it doesn't compile. Would that answer your question?

Comment: `this` is a pointer and you can't re-write it. `*this` represents the object itself.

Comment: i'm just confused , i can't pass this because concatenate function expect object itself  not this pointer , if i want to pass *this pointer , i will change my concatenate syntax to Mystring &Mystring::operator+(Mystring &rhs) const. is this correct??

Comment: The only immediate problem I see with the code is that `operator+` should take `const Mystring &rhs` parameter (note the `const`), same as `operator+=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at it like this:

```cpp
this = this + rhs;

// is the same as:

pointer_to_MyString = pointer_to_MyString + MyString;
```

That doesn't make any sense!

You need to deference them first. Or in other words, remove the "pointer"

```cpp
*this = *this + rhs;

// is the same as:

MyString = MyString + MyString;
```